# How to populate a xaml combobox with Image and Text

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am binding a Xaml Combobox. Can i use Stackpanel or List? Can u explain how to bind data in such a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start you'll need some data with public properties for the URI of the image and text you want to display with it. Here's a simple example to use below:

```
public class ImageOption
{
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }
    public string ImageText { get; set; }
}
```

You'll then need another public property to hold some collection of that data item. This property needs to be on an object that can be set as a DataContext somewhere in your view or can be assigned directly to your ComboBox in code-behind:

```
  public ObservableCollection<ImageOption> ImageList { get; private set; }
```

Assuming that the DataContext of some parent element of the ComboBox has been assigned to the object containing the ImageList property you can then use this to bind the collection and display a simple image and text for each item:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ImageText}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

You will probably also want some size constraints on your Image by setting MaxWidth and/or MaxHeight.